# Electron : How to display system RAM and CPU usage in real-time

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, sysinfo

so I'm trying to make an app that displays the cpu usage, ram usage, gpu usage and disk usage to a bar graph. I'm at the point where I can display the total percent of ram used but I am not able to update the value in real time and show it to the bar graph. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Code

dashboard.js

```
const os = require("os");
const fs = require("fs");
const { memoryUsage } = require("process");

const os_free_mem = os.freemem()
let free_mem = (Math.round(os_free_mem / (1024*1024)))
const os_total_mem = os.totalmem()
let total_mem = (Math.round(os_total_mem / (1024*1024)))

const cpu_usage = document.querySelector(".cpu_usage");
const ram_usage = document.querySelector(".ram_usage");
const gpu_usage = document.querySelector(".gpu_usage");
const disk_usage = document.querySelector(".disk_usage");
const free_mem_lbl = document.getElementById("mem")
const total_mem_lbl = document.getElementById("tmem")

// FUNCTIONS
function update_cpu_usage(cpu_usage, value) {
    value = Math.round(value);
    cpu_usage.querySelector(".cpu_usage_fill").style.width = `${value}%`;
  }
function update_ram_usage(ram_usage, value) {
    value = Math.round(value);
    ram_usage.querySelector(".ram_usage_fill").style.width = `${value}%`;
  }
function update_gpu_usage(gpu_usage, value) {
    value = Math.round(value);
    gpu_usage.querySelector(".gpu_usage_fill").style.width = `${value}%`;
  }
function update_disk_usage(disk_usage, value) {
    value = Math.round(value);
    disk_usage.querySelector(".disk_usage_fill").style.width = `${value}%`;
  }

function find_cpu_percent() {
    var free_mem_percent =  Math.round((free_mem / total_mem ) * 100);

    free_mem_lbl.innerText = `${free_mem_percent}`

}

find_cpu_percent();

tmem.innerText = `${total_mem}`

update_cpu_usage(cpu_usage, 55);
update_ram_usage(ram_usage, free_mem_percent);
update_gpu_usage(gpu_usage, 24);
update_disk_usage(disk_usage, 75)
```

dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dashboard.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e637815e35.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script> 
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul> 
              <li><a href="index.html"><ion-icon name="home-sharp"></ion-icon></a></li>
              <li><a href="dashboard.html"><ion-icon name="speedometer-outline"></ion-icon></a></li>
              <li><a href="create-rp.html"><i class="fas fa-clock-rotate-left"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="create-usb.html"><i class="fa-brands fa-usb"></i></a></li>
  
            </ul> 
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <h3>System Information</h3>
        <!-- Usage Bars -->
        <span class="cpu_text">CPU</span>
        <div class="cpu_usage">            
            <div class="cpu_usage_fill"></div>
        </div>

        <span class="ram_text">RAM</span>
        <div class="ram_usage">            
            <div class="ram_usage_fill"></div>
        </div>

        <span class="gpu_text">GPU</span>
        <div class="gpu_usage">            
            <div class="gpu_usage_fill"></div>
        </div>

        <span class="disk_text">DISK</span>
        <div class="disk_usage">            
            <div class="disk_usage_fill"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- System Specifications -->
        <div class="specs">
            <h3>System Specifications</h3>
            <h5>CPU</h5>
            <p class="info" id="cpu_name">CPU : </p>
            <p class="info" id="cpu_speed">Speed :</p>
            <p class="info" id="cpu_cores">Cores : </p>
            <p id="mem" style="margin-left: 200px; font-size:40px"></p>
            <p id="tmem" style="margin-left: 200px; font-size:40px"></p>
        </div>
        <script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>
    </div>  
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to use a setInterval or setTimeout to refresh the data each every seconds o every x seconds.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to run every 500ms. Could you please tell me where to add either of those function? I just started learning JavaScript and electron a few days ago so I don't know any of these functions or where to use them. Thx for the reply though